# 親ディレクトリにあるモジュールを使用すると ImportError になる

Tags: python

環境　windows10
言語　python3.5

pythonで書かれたプログラムをコマンドプロンプトから
実行してもエラーが出てしまいます

```
C:\Users\user\gv\ana>python AAA.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AAA.py", line 1, in <module>
    from lib import BBB
ImportError: cannot import name 'BBB'
```

というエラーが出ます。
(現在いるディレクトリがanaというディレクトリで、そこにAAA.pyというファイルもあります)
環境変数も変えましたがうまくいきませんでした。
今のところ次の手が思いつきません。
ちなみにほかのパソコンでは動作します。
そのためソースコードなどの問題ではないようです。
どなたかご教示いただければと存じます。

```
C:.
├─ana
│  └─ AAA.py
|  └─ __init__.py 
|
└─lib
　 └─ BBB.py

AAA.pyの中身

from lib import BBB
```

以上です。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `lib`なのか`_lib`なのか分かりませんがプレビュー見て罫線を修正してもらえればと思います。

Comment: libです。紛らわしくてすみません。

Answer (score 1):

親ディレクトリのパスはAAA.pyから見えないため、sys.pathに追加する方法はどうでしょうか。

```
import sys

sys.path.append('../')
from lib import BBB
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。なんとかできました！

Comment: @orwell  解決でいいのでしょうか？解決したのであれば解決した回答を承認して下さい。もし別の回答があるのでしたらご自身で回答を投稿後承認してください。